# how to correctly port forward bitcoin in VM ubuntu

Tags: port

hi im getting the error message

Unable to bind to [::]:8332 if i run bitcoind on my host windows /VM virtual box ubuntu 20.04

how to correctly port forward .
there are so many faulty information topics about this on the internet .

any help will be welcome

Comment: 8332 is the JSON-RPC port, not the Bitcoin port (which is 8333). What are you trying to do? What sources are you reading in order to try to do what you are trying to do? Which are the faulty topics you mention?

Comment: im trying to connect bitcoin core testnet and main to the internet via an VM virtualbox ubuntu

Comment: It should work _out of the box_, unless you want the Bitcoin network machines to connect to your machine as well. Do you want the Bitcoin network machines to connect to your machine? Or would you be good enough if your machine connects to the Bitcoin network machines?

Comment: it would be good enough if they connect to the bitcoin network

Comment: Maybe comment the version you are trying, maybe share your bitcoin.conf file, or the command line arguments you are using.